# how to print large array fully in chrome console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console, formatting, google-chrome-devtools

I want to print an array (uniqueNames) in the Chrome Console:

```
> console.log(uniqueNames)
```

but the problem I come across is that after

```
> ["Theodor", "Albertus", /* 95 other elements */ "Andreas", "Bernd", "Roland"…] <--- dots here
```

[image: screenshot]

How to print the full array like the first 100 elements? I want to copy it and use in another application. Or maybe it is possible to write this array from the Chrome Console to a file (also in one line, and not as whole log)?

Comment: Why should I ask Google to change Chrome just for me? If one want **format** the output in bash, one **format** it and do not ask bash developers to change bash. I just want to find the way to **format** the output string. Actually, already found it.
Yes - one possibility - to .append(uniqueNames), but it looks ugly (still unformatted)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

just join all the elements, separated in string with "," :

```
uniqueNames.join("\",\"")
```

Comment: Works, but leaves off the first and last quotation mark for me. Easy fix is just to use this: `"\"" + uniqueNames.join("\",\"") + "\""`

Answer (score 78):

To print the full array in the console you can do :
`console.log(JSON.stringify(uniqueNames))`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: actually it is an answer, i reformulated to make it more clear

Comment: yes, but IMO this answer is not entirely correct, because `JSON.stringify` will not print a string but convert to a string.

Comment: oh, you are right i kind of misread and thought he wanted to print from console and not from the code. answer edited.

Comment: Maybe you didn't answer the original question properly, but this is what most of us are looking for - thanks 

Comment: `console.log(JSON.stringify(uniqueNames, null, 2))` // for pretty format

Answer (score 8):

I was looking for [console.table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/table)(array):

[image]

Comment: If the array is large VS Code prints only part from the start and part from the middle. How can I print the whole array of 450 JSON Objects?

Answer (score 1):

If the main aim is to copy the output, store it in a variable and use the `copy` function.

```js
copy(myLargeContentVariable)
```