# Angular: querying firebase

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a query to my firebase database which pipe and subscribe to get it in an array. My problem its I have more than 400 registers and I need it all in just one array, and firebase it's returning an array for each 100 registers:

[image]

How do can I get it in just one array? Because I need it in that way to make my loop.

That's my query now:

```
this.firestore.collection<User>('users').valueChanges().pipe(take(1)).subscribe(users => {
    this.users = users;
    console.log(this.users);
    this._search$.next();
});
```

thanks for helping!

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Answer (score 1):

You **are** getting back one array, but Chrome's debug output **shows** large arrays as subsets of 100 items. But if your own code, you'll see that it's one array with a length of 477, and one contiguous range of indexes from 0 to 476.

Also see:

- [how to print large array fully in chrome console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151256/how-to-print-large-array-fully-in-chrome-console)

Comment: Thank's!! So it's a xy problem, I think I need to get into the first node of the array to loop my data. Do you know how do I get there?