# XLSX returns only 100 object as array of arrays in Next JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, excel, next.js, xlsx

I have a file upload system. It reads excel file and upload data to database (mongoose). When I `console.log(sheetData)` it returns array of arrays with the objects. The array inside arrays contain only 100 objects and then it create another array. Below is my code and images of the issue.

## Code

```
//Excel Upload
  const handleExcelSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = async (e) => {
      const data = e.target.result;
      const workbook = xlsx.read(data, { type: "binary" });
      const sheetNames = workbook.SheetNames[0];
      const workSheet = workbook.Sheets[sheetNames];
      const sheetData = xlsx.utils.sheet_to_json(workSheet, {
        header: "1",
      });
      const headers = sheetData[0];
      return convertToJson(headers, sheetData); // <--- returns array of arrays???
      dispatch(importExcel(sheetData)); // currently disabled for debugging
    };
    reader.readAsBinaryString(excelFile);
  };

  //Converts data to json. IDK if this is useful I received same data without this function
  const convertToJson = async (headers, data) => {
    const rows = [];
    data.forEach(async () => {
      let rowData = {};
      rows.forEach(async (element, index) => {
        rowData[headers[index]] = element;
      });
      rows.push(rowData);
    });
    setTableData(rows);
    console.log(tableData);
    return rows;
  };
```

### Image - Array of Arrays

[image: Two arrays with limit of 100 objects]
[image: Required data is inside those arrays.]

### Summary

Actually I want that only single array is created with all the objects in one array. Currently it is creating two arrays, with one array of limit with 100 objects, after 99th object it creates 2nd array and starts from 100th object. Is there any option that it create only one array with all 108 objects in it.

(This app is production so I have to hide those data. Sorry)

#### Thank You

Comment: It does not creates 2 array, it is just chrome console shows in this way... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151256/how-to-print-large-array-fully-in-chrome-console And i have no idea why `setTableData((rows) => [rows]);` is using [rows], it creates an array with only 1 element which is your 108 elements array. So clarify please the issue you have. Also, not sure where do we see 160 objects, i see only 108.

Comment: @SergeySosunov thanks for the reply. Actually I was debugging that array so I removed some fields out of 160. when I upload 100 elements it prints single array but when I added 8 more elements it showed 2nd array I have 160 elements but for debugging I was using on 108 sry for that mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. It was in my backend. I am sending an array of data so I used `for loop` to fetch and upload data to database in backend. The mistake was I was sending a response in between loop which was breaking it. The response was just for check backend data and was useless so I removed it and it worked. If anyone faces same issue in future then please check your `loops` if they break while the loop is running.